# Word cloud in python with three separate values

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, python-3.5, tableau-api, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud in python such that every word comes tagged in the colour of data source
Say I have:

```
comment         Data source
  Hello there     1  (red)
  Hello!          1  (red) 
  Hi there        2 (green)
  im good         3 (blue)
```

So basically a word cloud of all three comments  where every word is in the colour of it's respective data source so hello =>red, hi=>green and im, good=>blue. In case of 'there', the colour might be a separate colour (say orange) for words which come across tags red as well as green 
and some other colour, let's say purple, in case word appears in blue + red tags, ...

How do I do the same in python? All I can do is generate a simple word cloud using the following code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wordcloud = WordCloud(
                      stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                      background_color='white',
                      width=1200,
                      height=1000
                     ).generate(word_string)


plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

OR can is simply do this in tableau??

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a `color_func` and pass it as a keyword argument to `Wordcloud`. Color specifications need to be a valid PIL color specifications.
A conceptually simple way would be like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

word_string = ... 

def color_func(word, *args, **kwargs):
    if word in ['hello']:
        color = '#ff0000' # red
    elif word in ['hi']:
        color = '#00ff00' # green
    elif word in ['im', 'good']:
        color = '#0000ff' # blue
    elif word in ['there']:
        color = 'ffa500' # orange
    else:
        color = '#000000' # black
    return color

wc = Wordcloud(..., color_func=color_func, ...)
wc.generate(word_string)
```

As writing the function like this is a bit tedious, I would define a dictionary mapping words to colors and then encapsulate it in a function:

```
word_to_color = dict()

blue_words = ['im', 'good']
for word in blue_words:
    word_to_color[word] = '#0000ff' # blue

# etc

def color_func(word, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        color = word_to_color[word]
    except KeyError:
        color = = '#000000' # black
    return color
```

In the latter case, you need to make sure to define `color_func` **after** defining `word_to_color`.